# angular 2 ag-grid ts code: Can't make sample car grid to react on row click

Tags: angular

This is about *angular 2 ag-grid ts* code

I’m new in Angular (both 2 & JS); I need a row click be captured in a function with row object passed. The goal is to create a form for editing of a row.

I’m working on “*Cars*” grid example provided in *ag-grid-angular2-beta-ts-master.zip*

Inside `gridOption`, I put:

```
onRowClicked: function(event) { console.log('a row was clicked');
```

But the execution doesn’t go there when I click a grid row.
Can someone please advise what I do wrong?
Please see modified example (SampleAppComponent.ts) code  below.
Thank you in advance.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {AgGridNg2} from 'ag-grid-ng2/main';
import {GridOptions} from 'ag-grid/main';
import {GridOptionsWrapper} from 'ag-grid/main';
import {GridApi} from 'ag-grid/main';
import {Car} from './car';
import {CarService} from './car.service';

import 'ag-grid-enterprise/main';

var gridOptions: GridOptions;
var carService: CarService;


function myRowClickedHandler() {
    console.log('the row was clicked');
}


console.log("Component start");
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<ag-grid-ng2 
               class="ag-fresh" style="height: 300px"  
               [columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
               [rowData] = "rowData"
               [enableColResize]="true"
               [singleClickEdit]="true"
               [enableSorting]="true"
               [enableRangeSelection]="true"
               (cell-clicked)="onCellClicked($event)"
               >
               </ag-grid-ng2>  
              `,
    directives: [AgGridNg2],
    providers: [CarService]
})
export class SampleAppComponent {

    private gridOptions: GridOptions;
    private rowData: Object[];
    private api: GridApi;


    constructor(private _carService: CarService) {
     console.log("in Grid constructor...");   
     carService = this._carService;

     this._carService.getCars().then(CARS => this.rowData = CARS);


     this.gridOptions = {
       onRowClicked: function(event) { console.log('a row was clicked'); } //Doesn't work, never get here when I click
     }

    }

    columnDefs = [
        { headerName: "Make", field: "make" },
        { headerName: "Model", field: "model" },
        {
            headerName: "Price",
            field: "price",
            cellClass: 'rightJustify',
            cellRenderer: function (params: any) {
                return '$' + params.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","); //thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/28324/elias-zamaria
            }
        },
        { headerName: "Year", field: "year" },
    ];

/*
    // put data directly onto the controller; changed it, now it's set in service via mock-cars.ts

    rowData = [
        { make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000, year: 2013 },
        { make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000, year:  2014 },
        { make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000, year: 2015 },
        { make: "Honda", model: "CRV", price: 33000, year: 2016}
    ];
*/

};
```

Comment: As far as I can see, you never bind the `row-click` event

Answer (score 2):

I would rather configure the event on the component directly:

```
<ag-grid-ng2 
           class="ag-fresh" style="height: 300px"  
           [columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
           [rowData] = "rowData"
           [enableColResize]="true"
           [singleClickEdit]="true"
           [enableSorting]="true"
           [enableRangeSelection]="true"
           (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)" // <-----
           >
</ag-grid-ng2>
```

Quoted from the doc (https://ag-grid.com/best-angular-2-data-grid/index.php):

> **Events**: All data out of the grid comes through events. These use Angular 2 event bindings eg (modelUpdated)="onModelUpdated()". As you interact with the grid, the different events are fixed and output text to the console (open the dev tools to see the console).
>   See the list of supported events:

- https://ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/index.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the RowClicked event in the html and the method to the component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<ag-grid-ng2 
               class="ag-fresh" style="height: 300px"  
               [columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
               [rowData] = "rowData"
               [enableColResize]="true"
               [singleClickEdit]="true"
               [enableSorting]="true"
               [enableRangeSelection]="true"
               (cell-clicked)="onCellClicked($event)"
               (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)"
               >
               </ag-grid-ng2>  
              `,
    directives: [AgGridNg2],
    providers: [CarService]
})
export class SampleAppComponent {

    [...]
    onRowClicked() {
        console.log('a row was clicked');        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all; after adding according Dinistro advise, actual function body inside export class, I finally got the EVENT captured (see "a row was clicked") in the console. Now how can capture the the clicked row object? Many thanks in advance

Comment: i modified  onRowClicked to have 'event' param: onRowClicked(event: Event) {console.log('a row was clicked; row: ' + event.data.make);}. it worked; then i assign 'event.data' to currentRow: RenderedRow. It also worked but transpiler complains: error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Event'. I'll leave it for now, thanks a lot